# msysgit's cygwin tools failing on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, cygwin, mingw, msysgit

In the msysgit installation directory there's a bunch of Cygwin tools (sh, ssh, wc, ...) which git sometimes use.
When I install msysgit (1.7.11.msysgit.1) on a fresh Win8 VM sometimes I get into a state where the first time I run any of the Cygwin tools I get the following error:

```
      0 [main] us 0 init_cheap: VirtualAlloc pointer is null, Win32 error 487
AllocationBase 0x0, BaseAddress 0x68560000, RegionSize 0x3A0000, State 0x10000
D:\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin\sh.exe: *** Couldn't reserve space for cygwin's heap, Win32 error 0
```

The next time it will work and this happens once  for each of the tools.

Any ideas on why this happens, how it's fixed for a specific tool after a single run of it and how to fix it in the first place?

Comment: @StevenPenny: it relates in the sense that installing msysgit is what brings in those tools (\Program Files (x86)\Git\bin).